# Looped text changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an automatic text change (testimonials like ont [click and scroll down please to see changing testimonials](https://www.avehire.co.uk/)

```
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <a href="clients">
                            <div class="box">
                                <p>Testimonial 1</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author">Pete</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <a href="clients">
                            <div class="box">
                                <p>Testimonial 2</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author">Fiona</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <a href="clients">
                            <div class="box">
                                <p>Testimonial 3</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author">Helen</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <a href="clients">
                            <div class="box">
                                <p>Testimonial 4</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author">Laura</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

I need each testimonial to show for few seconds and then change to another one so only one is shown at time. I'm not a good programmer and was trying to find this on google but I didn't. Thank you for help.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but these are some likely reasons why the question *is* being downvoted: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/. Fixing some of these issues may get your question more useful responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
                <div class="testimonial">
                    <a href="clients">
                        <div class="box">
                            <p>Testimonial 1</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="author">Pete</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial">
                    <a href="clients">
                        <div class="box">
                            <p>Testimonial 2</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="author">Fiona</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial">
                    <a href="clients">
                        <div class="box">
                            <p>Testimonial 3</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="author">Helen</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial">
                    <a href="clients">
                        <div class="box">
                            <p>Testimonial 4</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="author">Laura</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

and jquery:

```
var divs = $('div[class^="testimonial"]').hide(),
i = 0;

(function cycle() { 

divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
          .delay(1000)
          .fadeOut(400, cycle);

i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

[>> working example <<](https://jsfiddle.net/tucado/byLhntmr/5/)